# Python - Error when opening two files

Tags: python, file

I have a .txt file with a lot of numbers.

What my code does is read through the file, if it finds a number it adds it to a list called duns. Once the length of duns is 9 it adds these numbers to another list called fileSize. Once the length of fileSize is 50 (so total of 450 numbers), I want to write the content of fileSize in a .txt file seperated by commas. And I want a file to be created for each 450 numbers.

My code basically works.
The problem I have is when I want to open the file in which fileSize should be written down.

Here is my code:

```
from os import chdir
import numbers

chdir("C:\\Users\\u1080476\\Desktop\\Code\\TMO")

filename = "DUNS_par_bloc.txt"

fileSize = []     
duns = []
count = 0
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9','0']


f = open(filename, "r")
while True:

    c = f.read(1)
    if not c:
        print("End of File")
        break
    print("read a character: ",c)
    for num in numbers:
        if c == num:
            if len(duns) < 9:
            duns.append(c) 
            else:
                fileSize.append(''.join(duns))
                duns = []
        if len(fileSize) == 50:
             chdir("C:\\Users\\u1080476\\Desktop\\Code\\TMO\\files")
             count += 1

             text_file = open(count,".txt", "a")
             strBigFile = ','.join(fileSize)
             text_file.write(strBigFile)

             text_file.close()
f.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u1080476\Desktop\Code\TMO\read.py", line 33, in <module>
    text_file = open(count,".txt", "a")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Can you add the error message? Regards

Comment: Is it this line `text_file = open(count,".txt", "a")`? Does it throw an error?

Comment: It looks like you want the output text files to be named `0.txt`, `1.txt`, `2.txt`, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimStopfer I added the error I get in the post. Yes, the output I want is 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, etc.

Comment: @Reti43 Yes, this is when the error happens. I added it to the post